# What is a pythonic way of finding maximum values and their indices for moving subarrays for numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have numpy ndarrays which could be 3 or 4 dimensional. I'd like to find maximum values and their indices in a moving subarray window with specified strides.

For example, suppose I have a 4x4 2d array and my moving subarray window is 2x2 with stride 2 for simplicity:

```
[[ 1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [ 5, 6, 7, 8], 
 [ 9,10,11,12], 
 [13,14,15,16]].
```

I'd like to find

```
[[ 6  8],
 [14 16]]
```

for max values and

```
[(1,1), (3,1),
 (3,1), (3,3)]
```

for indices as output.

Is there a concise, efficient implementation for this for ndarray without using loops?

Comment: [`view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) from scikit-image may be nice for this. It makes finding the maximum values really easy, but getting the corresponding indices will be tricky. There's also [`maximum_filter` from Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html) but again, the problem is the indices..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `stride_tricks`:

```
def make_panes(arr, window):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    r,c = arr.shape
    s_r, s_c = arr.strides
    w_r, w_c = window

    if c % w_c != 0 or r % w_r != 0:
        raise ValueError("Window doesn't fit array.")

    shape = (r / w_r, c / w_c, w_r, w_c)
    strides = (w_r*s_r, w_c*s_c, s_r, s_c)

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape, strides)

def max_in_panes(arr, window):
    w_r, w_c = window
    r, c = arr.shape
    panes = make_panes(arr, window)
    v = panes.reshape((-1, w_r * w_c))

    ix = np.argmax(v, axis=1)
    max_vals = v[np.arange(r/w_r * c/w_c), ix]

    i = np.repeat(np.arange(0,r,w_r), c/w_c)
    j = np.tile(np.arange(0, c, w_c), r/w_r)
    rel_i, rel_j = np.unravel_index(ix, window)
    max_ix = i + rel_i, j + rel_j

    return max_vals, max_ix
```

A demo:

```
>>> vals, ix = max_in_panes(x, (2,2))
>>> print vals
[[ 6  8]
 [14 16]]
>>> print ix
(array([1, 1, 3, 3]), array([1, 3, 1, 3]))
```

Note that this is pretty untested, and is designed to work with 2d arrays. I'll leave the generalization to *n-d* arrays to the reader...

Comment: This works nicely! The generalization was straightforward. Thanks!